# Custom Taxonomy Archive URL rewrite

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, archives

I would like to create an archive page with a list of my custom taxonomies that link to a page that shows posts with that taxonomy relationship.

I registered my taxonomy like this:

```
register_taxonomy('my_taxo', array('my_custom_post'), array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'label' => 'my taxo'
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus ' => true
            )
        );
```

What is the recommended way to create an archive page that can be visited at a url such as mysite.com/my_taxo or mysite.com/taxonomy/my_taxo.

Ideally the template file that will be used would be `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`.

Does this involve add_rewrite_rule? If so what might that look like?

Comment: Could you clarify: Are you wanting a list of taxonomy terms, with a link for each that points to an archive of posts using of that term?

Comment: yes, I need a list of the taxonomy terms. Each term will have a link to posts with that term. The part I am stuck on is the pretty URL and using an appropriate template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't generate an 'archive of terms' automatically. However, you're current permalink structure is set up so that:

```
www.example.com/my_taxo/my-term
```

points to the 'my-term' archive page of the 'my_taxo' taxonomy (listing all posts with the 'my-term' tag).

So what you can do is create a page with slug 'my_taxo':

```
www.example.com/my_taxo
```

Assign this page a custom template which simply lists the taxonomy terms with links.

The simpliest way would be to use [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'my_taxo',
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'hierarchical' => 1
  'title_li'     => ''
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you can use [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to return an array of terms in that taxonomy, which you can loop through and display the terms.

Neither will handle pagination automatically - but `get_terms` allows you to specify both a limit and an offset - so you could handle pagination yourself if this is necessary.

Comment: Great, I think I might have over thought this one. Creating a page in the admin will work just fine. We can leave the URL rewriting for another day... Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need any custom rewriting or did you want the taxonomy/my_taxi structure?

Comment: Well, if you wanted to avoid having to create the page in the admin for a url such as mysite.com/my-taxo I think it would require a url rewrite rule.